# Evaluate $\iint(x^3 + xy^2) dA$, of the domain of the disc centered at $(0,0)$ with radius $1$, restricted to first quadrant

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Evaluate

$$\iint_D x^2+xy^2\,dA$$

where $D=B_1(0) \cap\{(x,y)\,:\, x\ge 0\,, y\ge0\}$.

I believe this can be done using the type I and type II methods, but converting to polar would be easier, so this is what i did:

$$D = \{(r,\theta)\,:\, 0\le r\le1, 0\le \theta \le\pi/2)\}$$

So i plugged $x = r\cos\theta$ and $y = r\sin\theta$ into $x^3 + xy^2$ and attempted, but could not get the answer which is $1/5$.

ALSO A CONCERN: does the order of the integrals matter? For example, if we do integral from $0$ to $\pi/2$ first then integral from $0$ to $1$ or vice versa. How do we know which to do first?

Comment: Sounds like you forgot the Jacobian.  When you convert to polar, it "creates" an $r.$  The order of integration does not matter.

Comment: Oh yeah, i got rdrdthetha, so i can do any order of integration and get same result?

Comment: You should.  There is a little bit more to it, than I have the space for right here.  but much like $\frac {\partial^2 z}{\partial x\partial y}$ does not depend on the order of differentiation, reversing the processes does not depend on order, either.

Comment: Sweet, I just re did it both ways and got the answer, thanks both!

Comment: [Fubini's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem) gives  conditions where the order of integration does not matter.  It applies here so you can integrate in either order.

Answer (score 0):

$$\int\limits_{x=0}^1 dx \int\limits_{y = 0}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}} dy\ x^2 + x y^2 = {1 \over 15} + {\pi \over 16}$$